# Beans in Spring test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, spring-test

I have one user controller.

User controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserRestController {

private final UserService userService;

public UserRestController(final UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@GetMapping()
public User getInfo(
        final @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails
) {
    return userService.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
}

@PutMapping()
public User update(
        final @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails,
        final @RequestBody User user
) {
    User userInSystem = userService.findByUsername(
            userDetails.getUsername()
    );
    return userService.update(user, userInSystem);
}
}
```

I make some test for him.

Test User controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationArguments.class)
@Configuration // this annotation can be removed, the error will remain the same
@EnableAutoConfiguration //previous comment
public class TestUserRestController {

@Autowired
private UserRestController userRestController;

@Test
public void Test() {
    assertThat(userRestController).isNotNull();
}
}
```

And in the end, I have an error when running the test:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.daniil.ostrouh.notes.TestUserRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRestController'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.daniil.ostrouh.notes.rest.UserRestController' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

**Updates**
Project Structure: [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3fVz.png)

Comment: what happens when you only have `@SpringBootTest` for the test class ?

Comment: @R.G what you mean? not understand you

Comment: Could you please annotate the `TestUserRestController` with `@SpringBootTest` alone and try once. No other annotations are required at this point.

Comment: You are right. It's works. But he said " java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual not to be null" But you can see what my controller is not null. Do you know what is the matter?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong now. Without that controller bean autowired the test should not run. Could you please update the question with the latest code that worked ?

Comment: @R.G I will not change the question, it remained unresolved. What you suggested to me obviously will not work without "@RunWith" annotation

Comment: That is your call. I was just trying to help you out . Good Luck!

Comment: What is the FQCN of the `UserRestController`, the `ApplicationArguments` and the `TestUserRestController`. Also can you please post the `ApplicationArguments.java` file?

Comment: what is FQCN? ApplicationArguments is import from org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments; @Gebezs

Answer (score 0):

Every standard Spring Boot application should have a production class which is annotated with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. This annotation does a lot including signaling Spring about the root of the component scan. Component scan is used for auto-detecting Spring beans (`@Component`, `@RestController`, etc). The `@SpringBootTest` tries to auto-detect that class is the `classes` if left empty. If the `classes` has any value then the Spring context will contain only the specified classes (in this case The `ApplicationArguments` which does nothing here).

So you should remove the `classes` from `@SpringBootTest` and your packages should be structured in hierarchy as the component scan uses this hierarchy.
If you need more help please post your project.

Comment: After deleting "classes" from @SpringBootTest i have Error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Comment: Do you have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`?
Can you post your project?

Comment: Yes, i have this annotation in main class. May be error is caused due to incorrect structure. I pin image in post question, can you watch this please?